# condition to button for members and visitors

Tags: php, css, wordpress, web

how can i add a condition to a button ? for visitors it will be LOGIN for logged in it will be changed to `LOGOUT`

another button will appear if member log in and disappear if he logged out

its a wordpress website and iam newbie in coding so please clarify where to put the code exactly

iam using button plugin for this button and i will put these buttons in the header area (above the navigation menu)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu81j.png)

Comment: do you want to do it in wordpress?

Comment: yes wordpress website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tagged `wordpress`,so you can do it like below:-

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()){?>
// your logout and other button code
<?php }else{?>
// your login button code
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: hello sir , thanks for answering. where i put this code exactly? in the button css or the style sheet of the theme? . can you have alook at the image and edited question please

Comment: @Bobneverstop  in your header.php or function.php file where you are adding this button code

Comment: @Bobneverstop you put that code on the place u wanna show the page on

Comment: @AlivetoDie hello sir and thanks the code worked fine.but a small problem look at image . i need the button just above the navigation menus not that far. how i do it? i placed your code in header right area with genesis hooks.http://imgur.com/bDC4Oiw

Comment: @Bobneverstop  for that you have to do `Css` adjustment. it's not coding part. it's designing part.Do it through `Css`

Comment: @AlivetoDie do you suggest any easy tool for that css ? sorry because iam really don't know much about this stuff

Comment: @Bobneverstop  not tool. do some css code and change according to your desired way. Otherwise hier a designer for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said is WordPress, what you want is super simple, write on the place where you want the button to show just add this simple one line code

```
<p class="mybtn"><?php wp_loginout(); ?></p>
```

then just style the p tag to look like a button

the function `wp_loginout();` displays a login link, or if a user is logged in, displays a logout link.

You don't need any complicated if statements.

Answer (score 0):

For LOGGED in user you will maintain some flag either in session or cookies.
If this flag is set show the button as "Logout" & write the logout functionality on click of the button, & if flag is "OFF" then show "Login" button

Comment: Proper answer to a poorly asked question.

Comment: hello sir thanks for reply , can you look at the edited question and the image